# Display MySQL "GROUP BY" results correctly

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I cannot seem to get this query displayed properly. Here is the code:

```
$select_stats = "SELECT 
  c.ResponderID
  , COUNT(MsgID)
  , a.SubscriberID
  , CanReceiveHTML
  , EmailAddress 
FROM InfResp_msglogs AS a
  , InfResp_subscribers AS b
  , InfResp_responders AS c 
WHERE b.CanReceiveHTML = 1 
  AND c.owner='".$_SESSION['logged_user_id']."' 
  AND c.ResponderID = b.ResponderID 
  AND b.SubscriberID = a.SubscriberID 
GROUP BY c.ResponderID";

//echo $select_result;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_result))
{
    $messages = $row['COUNT(MsgID)'];
    $campaign = $row['ResponderID'];
    $subscriber = $row['SubscriberID'];
    $subscriber_email = $row['EmailAddress'];

    echo "<br>Campaign = ". $campaign ."
          <br>Sent emails count = ". $messages ."
          <br>Subscriber Nr. = ". $subscriber ."
          <br>Subscriber Email = ". $subscriber_email ."<br>";
     }
```

This is the output:

```
Campaign = 10
Sent emails count = 109
Subscriber Nr. = 95
Subscriber Email = timothy@gmail.com

Campaign = 11
Sent emails count = 16
Subscriber Nr. = 97
Subscriber Email = alan@yahoo.com
```

As there are three different subscribers under campaign no.10 and one under campaign no.11 in the db (each with its own email addresses of course), I would like the output to be:

```
Campaign = 10
Sent emails count = 109
Subscriber Nr. = 92
94
95
Subscriber Email = timothy@gmail.com
anthony@yahoo.com
josie@hotmail.com

Campaign = 11
Sent emails count = 16
Subscriber Nr. = 97
Subscriber Email = alan@yahoo.com
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for this:

```
... SELECT c.ResponderID, COUNT(MsgID), a.SubscriberID, CanReceiveHTML, 
group_concat(EmailAddress ORDER BY EmailAddress DESC SEPARATOR ' ') ...
```

Comment: But beware of `group_concat_max_len`